# UITextView Detect Character Removed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I created a `UITextView` which allows dynamic tagging when the user types `@`.

Is it possible to detect a `@` removed, in order to stop my specific tagging process that I created? If so, how can I do that? `UITextView` has no such delegate methods.

Comment: can you elaborate more on 'dynamic tagging'. how are you implementing this?

Comment: @darksky can you give the solution of this? have you implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I would use

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

Then create an `NSString` in which you store the last character added to the `UITextView`.  Within the above method, add the following snippet.

```
if ([text isEqualToString:@""] && [lastRecordedString isEqualToString@"@"]) {
  //do whatever you want to do when an @ is deleted
}

lastRecordedString = [textView.text substringFromIndex:[string length]-1];
```

EDIT: see the edited code above.  Now `lastRecordedString` is the last character in the `UITextView` after a character is removed.  This should work.

Comment: When text is equal to `""` in the `shouldChangeTextInRange`, is it necessarily to be a backspace?

Comment: That way only assumes taht the user has entered `@` then removed it. What if a user has entered `@Hello` and removed the whole thing? Last recorded string would still be `o`.

Comment: What happens if a user has entered `@Hello` then clicked to manually change the cursor and deleted the `@`? The last character would still be `o` but a character in the middle has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can get the original text which will be replaced by use:

```
NSString *originalText = [textView.text substringWithRange:range];
```

in your

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

method.

Then, do

```
if ([originalText rangeOfString:@"tag"].length > 0) {
    NSLog(@"delete tag string");
}
```

You will detect if user delete a specific string.

Hope that helpful!